# Post request pending but data saved , how to make the request success?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

so I am trying to send a POST request to the server using Axios so I can register new users.
When I fill the form and submit , the request stays in pending status . When I use redux tools and the network console I see that the data I sent to the server is correct and when I try to log in with the new user I success even tho the POST request status is still pending . Why is the request doesn't success ? and what is the best way to prevent/track this kind of errors?
Thanks

store.js

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, compose, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from   'redux-thunk';
import {productDetailsReducer, productListReducer} from './reducers/productReducer';
import {cartReducer} from './reducers/cartReducer';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { userRegisterReducer, userSigninReducer } from './reducers/userReducer';

const cartItems= Cookies.getJSON("cartItems") || [] ;
const userInfo= Cookies.getJSON("userInfo") || null ;


const initialState={cart : {cartItems}   , userSignin: {userInfo}  };



const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer , 
    productDetails: productDetailsReducer   , 
    cart: cartReducer ,
    userSignin : userSigninReducer ,
    userRegister: userRegisterReducer
} );

const composeEnchancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose ; 

const store=createStore( reducer , initialState , composeEnchancer(applyMiddleware(thunk)) ) ;


export default store;
```

userRoute

```
router.post('/register' , async (req,res)=>{
    const user = User ({
        name : req.body.name , 
        email : req.body.email , 
        password : req.body.password,
       
    });

    const newUser = await user.save() ;

    if(newUser){
        res.send({
            _id:newUser.id ,
            name:newUser.name ,
            email:newUser.email,
            isAdmin: newUser.isAdmin ,
            token: getToken(signinUser)
            
        } );

    }

    else {
        res.status(401).send({msg:'invalid email or password'})
    }

})
```

actions

```
 const register = (name ,email,password)=>async dispatch=>{
    dispatch({ type: USER_REGISTER_REQUEST, payload:{name, email,password }});
    try {
        const {data}= await Axios.post("/api/users/register" , {name, email , password});
        dispatch({type:USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS , payload:data});
        Cookies.set('userInfo' , JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    catch(error){
       dispatch({type:USER_REGISTER_FAILED , payload:error.message});
    }
}

 export {signin , register }
```

reducer

```
function userRegisterReducer (state= {} , action){
    
    switch (action.type) {

        case USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS:
            return {loading: false , userInfo: action.payload};


        case USER_REGISTER_REQUEST:
            return {loading:true};


        case USER_REGISTER_FAILED:    
        return {loading:false , error:action.payload}
            
         
    
        default:
           return state ;
    }
}
```

from the server.js `app.use("/api/users" , userRoute);`

Comment: It does work when I res.send(newUser) . the problem happens only when I try to res.send({someObject})

Answer (score -1):

what about adding the actual status to the response?

```
res.status(201).send({
        _id:newUser.id ,
        name:newUser.name ,
        email:newUser.email,
        isAdmin: newUser.isAdmin ,
        token: getToken(signinUser)
        
    } );
```